Druid rabbitmq stream spec json is not working
{
"type": "rabbit",
"spec": {
  "dataSchema": {
    "dataSource": "metrics-rabbit",
    "timestampSpec": {
      "column": "createdOn",
      "format": "auto"
    },
   "dimensionsSpec": {
      "dimensions": ["clientInfo", "createdOn", "duration", "endedOn", "id", "islessonitemavailable", "startedOn", "state", "status", "updatedOn", "userId", "userRole"]
    },
   "metricsSpec": [],
   "granularitySpec": {
      "type": "uniform",
      "segmentGranularity": "HOUR",
      "queryGranularity": "NONE"
   }
 },
 "ioConfig": {
  "type": "rabbit",
  "stream": "queue_session_tracker",
  "uri": "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/vhost"    
},
 "tuningConfig": {
   "type": "rabbit",
   "maxRowsPerSegment": 5000000
 }
}
}

It is unable to connect rabbitmq url
